# CRM tracing for plugin but not for custom workflow activity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I use the the tracing service of CRM for plugins and custom workflow activities. The plugins run in sandbox mode, the custom workflow activities in non-sandbox mode.

One of my plugins starts a custom workflow. I see trace logs during the execution of the plugin, but no trace logs are written for my custom workflow activity.

I have restarted the CRM services also, still no logs

What can be wrong here ?

Here is some code:

```
   public class MyPlugin : Plugin
   {
      protected override void Execute(RuntimeContext context)
      {
         var actionToExecute = new OrganizationRequest("MyActivity")
         {
         }

         context.MyOrganizationService.Execute(actionToExecute);
      }
    }

    public class MyActivity : CodeActivity
    {
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            var context = new RuntimeContext(executionContext);

            var tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

            tracingService.Trace("Hello world");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What tracing are we talking about here?

Comment: See the code snippet I added to the original post.

Comment: Try to set it as an ITracingService instead of a var, don't know if it makes any difference but sometimes it can be sort of picky. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334455.aspx

Comment: I am facing the same issue? Does anyone know why it is behaving so?